# Add class when div is in the center of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class, for a joomla website, to a div when the div reaches the center of the screen horizontally.

```
   var horizontalCenter = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/2);
 var caseItem = "ul#caroufredsel_226 li.item";
 if (caseItem = horizontalCenter) {
    jquery(caseItem).addClass('no-blur');
 }
```

EDIT

After further research, I have found another solution:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function(){
    var caseItem = jQuery('ul#caroufredsel_226 li.item');
    jQuery(caseItem).each(function(){
        var centerLine = jQuery(window).width()/2;
        var divStart = jQuery(this).offset().left;
        var divEnd = divStart + jQuery(this).width();
        if(divStart < centerLine && divEnd > centerLine){
            jQuery(caseItem.addClass('no-blur'));
        }
    });
});
```

However this solution appears to just add the class to every div immediately.

Comment: `var caseItem = "$(ul#caroufredsel_226 li.item)"; if (caseItem.width() == horizontalCenter) { caseItem.addClass('no-blur');`

Comment: @bipen the first instruction should be `var caseItem = $("ul#caroufredsel_226 li.item");`

Comment: thanks for the reply, these changes didnt work either, not class is being added to the div